# Taskbar not showing

Tags: xfce

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 (Xfce)

My task bars are not showing. This is what my apps look like when I open them. They are also not showing in my Xfce panel.

[image]

Comment: Please help im new to using linux and i use this pc for school

Comment: I also cant alt-tab and alt-f4 but my keyboard is responding

Comment: Reinstallation of Xubuntu task package by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^` may help. Then reboot.

Comment: Its still the same

Comment: I also cant exit them cause theres no "x" button

Comment: `sudo reboot` from already running terminal or from Ctrl+Alt+F3 text terminal should work.

Comment: It maybe the result of themes you've chosen to use; from your picture I can't make out what it's showing (a full desktop isn't visible), but I do know some themes don't have buttons intentionally by design, and if you've removed your panel via command it may not return (without manual edit; though if you just killed it; it should re-appear on logout/login again).

Comment: Hello, update i got it fixed by changing my desktop environment the taskbars are showing again, thanks for all the help. I will update if anything else comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my desktop environment thanks everyone for the help